# Text value not being got or set in jquery

Tags: jquery, typescript, svelte

I was having an issue setting the text of an element in jquery. My code is as follows:

```
function renameLink(): void {
    console.log(j$("#renametext").val())
    console.log(j$(this).parentsUntil('.element').children(".linkname").children(".linkname").text())
    j$(this).parentsUntil('.element').children(".linkname").children(".linkname").val(String(j$("#renametext").val()));
    j$("#renametext").val("");
  }
```

When I console.log `".linkname".text()` text value, I'm getting an empty string, and when I log `".linkname".html()`, it returns `undefined`.

Here is the HTML (svelte) that I am trying to modify:

```
        <figure 
          class="element"
          animate:flip = "{{duration: 300}}"
          out:scale="{{duration: 250}}"
          in:scale="{{duration: 250}}"
          draggable={true}>

            <span class="mb-3 truncate linkname">
              <a href="https://{element}" target="_blank" id="linkname"  class="linkname link">
                {element}
              </a>
            </span>
            
            <button class="element-btn dropdown-btn" on:click="{() => openDropdown(this, i)}">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
            
            <Modal />
            
            <!-- <br> -->

            {#if buttonsVisible[i] != undefined && buttonsVisible[i]} 
              <button tabindex="0" class="copy-btn element-btn" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="focus"
              title="Copy link"
              data-bs-content="Link copied!" on:click="{() => writeClipboard(element)}">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-clipboard"></i>
              </button> <!--copy link button-->

              <button class="element-btn" on:click="{() => openModal()}" title="Edit link">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-pen"></i>
              </button> <!--edit button-->

              <button class="element-btn" on:click="{() => removeEntry(element)}" title="Remove link">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
              </button> <!--delete button-->
            {/if} 
          </figure>
```

How do I get it to return the actual text? It starts off with text in it.

Comment: Do you mean `$(".linkname").text()`?

Comment: Why would you even want to do this? When you are using Svelte, you should not query the DOM to modify it.

Comment: @H.B. What would you recommend I do? I have a series of cards that I need to change the text of based on the input of a modal.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes, I just simplified it for conciseness.

Comment: You would update some local state which should be passed to components responsible for rendering the cards. It's the core method of using Svelte; you should do [the tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/) if you have not already.

Comment: If you cross between Svelte and non-Svelte contexts you may have to pass data through stores or use the client-side API to [update component props](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api-$set).

Comment: Thanks a ton! I'll check those out.